# Are adult converts to Eastern Orthodoxy required to use their baptismal names outside of church?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, baptism, name

There seems to be various opinions on this topic. Some say that it is absolutely necessary to completely adopt this new name while others say that it is recommended to use it outside of church but it is not required. Is there any kind of consensus on this in the various branches?

Comment: Not strictly relevant, but in Russian Orthodox Church it is not required. Moreover, in most cases these names match.

Comment: If your name is already a saint or could be derived from one, there is rarely a difference. This is more so for converts from non-Orthodox backgrounds. Even so, it is rare to use the saint name for non-ordained folks. Priests use their new name quite often from what I’ve seen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Catholic, not Orthodox but according to this site it is something that should be done but not required

"In placing such great emphasis on this tradition and in expressing our regret that so many converts to the Orthodox Church ignore it"

"It is essential, indeed, that converts take the name of an Orthodox Saint, use it in all circumstances,"

http://orthodoxinfo.com/praxis/orthname.aspx